# Input Handler not working as intended C++

Tags: c++, error-handling, console

I am trying to make a program that reads from the keyboard a number corresponding to an index of an answer for a question and returns an error message if the type of date entered is wrong.

```cpp
float Handlers ::InputHandler(string Question, unsigned short int Number_of_Answers)
{

    float Answer;

    cout << Question << endl << endl;
    while (!(cin >> Answer) || Answer < 1 || Answer > Number_of_Answers || Answer - floor(Answer))
    {
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            ErrorHandler(InputErrorNumber);
        }
    }

    return Answer;
}
```

The program worked perfectly until I entered the value 1ddga (and other cases that respect the form 1 or 2 + string, 1 and 2 are the answers that the person can choose from). After I entered the respective value, the program continues with answer 1 and then if I try to ask for an answer using the same function, it returns the error message, after the question and then asks for my input. It is as if from 1ddga it read 1, and the rest was stored somewhere, and on the next reading, this save was checked and then it continued to ask for another input.

Is there any solution? For example, can I return to that while after it has read such a value, or at least stop the error message on the next reading?

[image: Here it asks for my input]

[image: Here I add a wrong value]

[image: and here is the case where I enter the specified value (it continued running and showed me the message on the next reading)]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: " It is as if from 1ddga it read 1" that is correct. "the rest was stored somewhere" no, it was never even read. Do you know about `std::getline`, and how to use it? If your goal here is to read a line of input, followed by a newline, then this is what `std::getline` is for, not `>>`.

Comment: you should post text as text. The screenshots are unreadable. Also post a [mcve], enough code so that others can reproduce the problem

Comment: why do you read a `float` and then require it to be an integer rather than simply reading an `int`?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number i want to throw an error message when a float value is introduced . If i had the data type as int it will convert the value and continue the program without throwing an error message.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik until now I used getline for char arrays. how would it look used in this context?

Comment: @AndreiVoicea "it" will not throw an error, but you can check if something is left over in the stream an throw your error. Btw try to be careful with terminology, your function returns a `float`, it does not return a error message. I suppose you mean "It throws an exception that comes with a message", but not sure

Comment: It would look the same exact way, `std::getline` works the same exact way, every time, except that it's better to use `std::getline` with a `std::string`, instead. Then, after a simple check to verify that the resulting string contains only digits, use any one of the many ways to parse it into a float value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is as if from 1ddga it read 1, and the rest was stored somewhere

That's completely correct, if by 'stored somewhere' you mean that it remains in the console buffer waiting to be read next time around. This is how `operator>>` on an `float` is defined to work. It reads characters until it finds a character which cannot be part of a float, at that point it stops.

When you have precise input requirements then the only way to handle that is to do the error checking yourself. Read the input as a string, using `getline` for example. Then check if the input matches your expectations and then convert the string read into the value you want.

In your case, for example, you might read a string using `getline`, remove any leading or trailing whitespace, check if all the characters left are digits, and finally check that there is at least one digit. If all of that is true convert the string into an integer, otherwise do some kind of error handling.